# Dynamically load spring bean properties from database or Java Objects )

Tags: spring, web-services, properties

I have a scenario where I need to load properties from database or java object into beans.

Consider the example:

```
<bean id="ConfigAsstDemoBeanParent" class="gps.springconfig.DemoClass" lazy-init="true">
  <property name="demoValueFromBean" value="demoValue"></property>
  <property name="demoValueForKeyFromProperties" value="${DEMO_KEY}"></property>
</bean>
```

and instead of the `${DEMO_KEY}` property placeholder, which loads a value from the property file, I need to load a value from the database, which I retrieve using a stored procedure from a Java class.

Please suggest me a mechanism which I can leverage for the above scenario. Currently I am investigating extending SpringMain and/or PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class and write my own custom BootStrapper.

Also please suggest hints on writing a BootStrapper for the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: I use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer for stuff like this.

Comment: @RockyTriton but as I understand PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer only be used to resolve properties from .properties file. I dont really see how it can be used for getting values from DB. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the cases where Java configuration seems to be a great alternative:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public DemoClass configAsstDemoBeanParent() {
        DemoClass demo = new DemoClass();
        demo.setDemoValueFromBean("demoValue");
        demo.demoValueForKeyFromProperties( /* query the database here */);
        return demo;
    }

}
```

Note that you can inject `DataSource` (or `JdbcTemplate`) to your `@Configuration` class providing it was defined elsewhere.

Comment: +1 Also, you don't have to write any custom bootstrap. You can load this class as described here -> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.0.html#new-feature-java-config

Comment: This is awesome.. works perfectly.. I little thing though. I have lots of beans like the one defined above, and lot more property placeholders.. Can you please give me any suggestions on making it generic, where I can get all the values for the key using a Generic class that does the DB calls...

Comment: @kanap008: if you already have these beans defined in XML with property placeholders, you'll better stay with XML. You can also try auto-generating `@Configuration` classes.