# Spring: bean initializing values from DB

Tags: java, spring

I've read that I can set bean initialization properties in .properties file. I can do that with help of `PropertyBeanPlaceholderConfigurer`.

I want to do the same, but pull bean initialization properties from DB instead.

1. Have Spring got a standart realization for factory post processor which will help me to pull initialization properties from DB? Which?
2. If haven't, how can I realizate it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to look for DB values and use properties file as fallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098140/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-to-look-for-db-values-and-use-properties-file-as-f)

Comment: Seems to be done easily using JavaConfig; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11161604/491897) for details

Comment: @BenS thanks. But if I don't want to rewrite the whole application config for single bean initialization.

Comment: I 've found the answer through the reference pointed above: http://pure-essence.net/2011/02/10/spring-loading-properties-from-database-with-a-twist/

Comment: You wouldn't need to rewrite the entire application config.  Java config is used in addition to any existing xml config.